# Pyspark: null value after from_json conversion

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, databricks

I am trying to stream structured data from Azure eventhub to databricks using pyspark. Unfortunately I can t deal with some problems. Here is my code that send my json to eventhub (using binding to eventhub):

```py
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> str:
  API = "https://ckan2.multimediagdansk.pl/gpsPositions"
  r = requests.get(API).json()["Vehicles"]
  return json.dumps(r)
```

And here is my databricks code:

```py
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Streaming") \
.getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
StructField("DataGenerated", TimestampType()),
StructField("Line", IntegerType()),
StructField("Route", StringType()),
StructField("VehicleCode", IntegerType()),
StructField("VehicleService", StringType()),
StructField("VehicleID", IntegerType()),
StructField("Speed", IntegerType()),
StructField("Delay", IntegerType()),
StructField("Lat", DoubleType()),
StructField("Lon", DoubleType()),
StructField("GPS Quality", IntegerType()),
])

stream = (spark \
.readStream \
.format("eventhubs") \
.options(**ehConf) \
.load())

mess = stream.withColumn('Body', stream['body'].cast('string')) \
         .select("Body")
```

Everything seems to good. Here is display of my message:

[image: display_1]

The problem starts here. I want to load this body into my dataframe (code comes from one of the tutorials from the internet)

```
df = mess.select(from_json(col("body"), schema).alias("data")).select("data.*")
```

As a result I got this:

[image: display_2]

As you can see, some of my Integer values are converted to null. When I convert this to string in my schema everything is good. I am not really good at spark so it s possible that I am making stupid mistakes that I can t really understand. Do you know where could be a problem here?

Comment: There is `VehicleId`  field and  not `VehicleID` in the eventhubs stream body. Also `Line` field is of `StringType` and not `IntegerType`.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thank you for spoting this `VehicleId`. What do you mean that something is `StringType` ? I would like to have it in `IntegereType`, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: You can cast from StringType to IntegerType after parsing. However you have to have your schema match the data schema to parse it correctly.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Ok, thank you for your help. I think now I understand how it works :)